# How to write function in Julia v1.1 that inputs multi-dimensional array?

Tags: function, multidimensional-array, julia

I am trying to write a function in Julia that takes in a multi-dimensional array (a data cube) and rescales every entry from 0 to 1. However, whenever I run the code in atom, I get the error

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching -(::Array{Float64,2}, ::Float64)
Closest candidates are:
  -(::Float64, ::Float64) at float.jl:397
  -(::Complex{Bool}, ::Real) at complex.jl:298
  -(::Missing, ::Number) at missing.jl:97
  ...
Stacktrace:
[1] rescale_zero_one(::Array{Float64,2}) at D:\Julio\Documents\Michigan_v2\CS\EECS_598_Data_Science\codex\Codex_3\svd_video.jl:40
[2] top-level scope at D:\Julio\Documents\Michigan_v2\CS\EECS_598_Data_Science\codex\Codex_3\svd_video.jl:50 [inlined]
[3] top-level scope at .\none:0
in expression starting at D:\Julio\Documents\Michigan_v2\CS\EECS_598_Data_Science\codex\Codex_3\svd_video.jl:48
```

I have the basics of what my function must do, but I really don't understand some of the notation and what the error is telling or how to fix it.

```
function rescale_zero_one(A::Array)
    B = float(A)
    B -= minimum(B)
    B /= maximum(B)
    return B
end

m,n,j = size(movie_cube)
println(j)
C = Array{Float64}(UndefInitializer(),m,n,j)
for k in 1:j
    println(k)
    C[:,:,j] = rescale_zero_one(movie_cube[:,:,j])
end
```

the variable movie_cube is a 3 dimensional data array of Float64 entries and I just want to rescale the entries from zero to one. However, the error that I mentioned keeps appearing. I would really appreciate any help with this code!

Comment: I think you are using the wrong index in the loop. You are looping over `k` but use `j` in the indexing expression (this is not the cause of your error, thoug.)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use dot syntax for doing some operations in an array!

```
function rescale_zero_one(A::Array)
    B = float.(A)
    B .-= minimum(B)
    B ./= maximum(B)
    return B
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Even with the new code 
    function rescale_zero_one(A::Array)
        B = float.(A)
        B .-= minimum(B)
        B ./= maximum(B)
        return B
    end

movie_cube = rescale_zero_one(movie_cube)

I still have the same error, do you have an idea of what could be happening?

Comment: The solution by @Pei Huang works correctly, the error is somewhere else. Can you (@user110320) cut and paste a full example that reproduces the error (preferably with a small input array)?

Answer (score 1):

This code is a bit faster and simpler (it only makes two passes over the input matrix rather than five in the previous answer):

```
function rescale(A::Matrix)
    (a, b) = extrema(A)
    return (A .- a) ./ (b - a)
end
```

This can be generalized to three dimensions, so that you don't need the outer loop over the dimensions in `C`. Warning: this solution is actually a bit slow, since `extrema`/`maximum`/`minimum` are slow when using the `dims` keyword, which is quite strange:

```
function rescale(A::Array{T, 3}) where {T}
    mm = extrema(A, dims=(1,2))
    a, b = first.(mm), last.(mm)
    return  (A .- a) ./ (b .- a)
end
```

Now you could just write `C = rescale(movie_cube)`. You can even generalize this further:

```
function rescale(A::Array{T, N}; dims=ntuple(identity, N)) where {T,N}
    mm = extrema(A, dims=dims)
    a, b = first.(mm), last.(mm)
    return  (A .- a) ./ (b .- a)
end
```

Now you can normalize your multidimensional array along any dimensions you like. Current behaviour becomes

```
C = rescale(movie_cube, dims=(1,2))
```

Rescaling each row is

```
C = rescale(movie_cube, dims=(1,))
```

Default behaviour is to rescale the entire array:

```
C = rescale(movie_cube)
```

One more thing, this is a bit odd:

```
C = Array{Float64}(UndefInitializer(),m,n,j)
```

It's not wrong, but it is more common to use the shorter and more elegant:

```
C = Array{Float64}(undef, m, n, j)
```

You might also consider simply writing: `C = similar(movie_cube)` or `C = similar(movie_cube, Float64)`.

**Edit:** Another general solution is to not implement the dimension handling in the `rescale` function, but to rather leverage `mapslices`. Then:

```
function rescale(A::Array)
    (a, b) = extrema(A)
    return (A .- a) ./ (b - a)
end

C = mapslices(rescale, A, dims=(1,2))
```

This is also not the fastest solution, for reasons I don't understand. I really think this ought to be fast, and might be sped up in a future version of Julia.